# XSLT Insert html content

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to insert some HTML at a given point. The XML file has a content node, which inside that has actual HTML. For exmaple here is the content section of the XML:

```
-----------------
<content>
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <p><a href="...">some link</a></p>
    <p><a href="...">some link1</a></p>
    <p><a href="...">some link2</a></p>
</content>
-----------------
```

I need to insert a link after the header but before the first link, inside its own p tag. A little rusty with XSLT, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this source:

```
<html>
    <head/>
    <body>
        <content>
            <h2>Header</h2>
            <p><a href="...">some link</a></p>
            <p><a href="...">some link1</a></p>
            <p><a href="...">some link2</a></p>
        </content>
    </body>
</html>
```

This stylesheet will do what you want to do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/html/body/content/h2">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <p><a href="...">your new link</a></p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Both helped but it was nice to see the entire thing put together like this helped me understand more. Good answer thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/content">
        <xsl:copy-of select="h2"/>
        <a href="">foo</a>
        <xsl:copy-of select="p"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```